# Symfony2 - Where to find service constructor possible arguments list?

Tags: php, symfony

Where can I find full list of possible service constructor arguments like: `@request`, `@service_container`, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listing available services

```
$ app/console container:debug
```

Information about a specific service

```
$ app/console container:debug request
```